# Rewriting git commit history

Tags: git, git-rebase

Assuming we have a git commit history which looks like:

> ZZ [origin/master] A -> B -> C -> D -> E [master]

We want to:

- Rewind the history back to before `A`.
- Keep the working directory of `E`.
- Bundle all the changesets of `A..E` in to a single commit.
- Push the outcome to remote.

The result should look like:

> ZZ -> XX [master][origin/master]

Where XX is the commit encompassing the changes of prior commits A..E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
git reset --hard E
git reset --soft ZZ
git commit 'comment'
git push orgin master
```

> **--soft**
>
> Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just likeall modes do). This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would putit.

Comment: Quick, simple, elegant. Thanks.